# IP pool in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Our applications very often have IP addresses which are banned in our country. Some site in our IP pool in GAE have braken a law and so we have ban with this site.

How can I select for our application another pool of IP? Is there another solution.

Comment: Its not possible with GAE, you may use Managed VMs thought. They have unique IP addresses. Or just try to explain this to those who has banned them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately one of the biggest strengths in GAE is that it scales without you having to get involved, so basic GAE apps have a completely transparent IP assignment.

Your only chance of getting a fixed IP is to host your app in a [compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) instance which gets a fixed IP you can validate with your ISP or whoever is banning the IPs.

As @Dmitry Sadonvchyi states if you already have a GAE app you can move that to a [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) which basically allows you to run GAE applications outside the standard "sandbox" and into a VM you control.